# How to detect if the requested image doesn't have errros (403 Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that loads an image from a source every 300 ms but sometimes I get back a `403 Forbidden` response. In that case, the image source becomes blank, so I would like to somehow check if the image has a response of 200 and only then update my image element. How could I achive that?

**Here is my code**

```
<body>
    <!-- Live view -->
    <img class="screenshot" src="screenshot.jpg">

    <script>
        setInterval(() => {
            // Sometimes I get back a 403 forbidden
            document.querySelector('.screenshot').src = 'http://192.168.1.150:80/screen/screenshot.jpg?id=' + Math.random(0, 10000)
        }, 300)
    </script>
</body>
```

I would like to be able to do something like this

```
    if (status == 200) {
        document.querySelector('.screenshot').src = 'http://192.168.1.150:80/screen/screenshot.jpg?id=' + Math.random(0, 10000)
    } else {
        // Do nothing, keep the old image
    }
```

Comment: Might be valuable for you is `onerror`.  `<img src="url.jpg" onerror="call function to get another image">`. This would make it so that there was less delay if an image is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
const imgTag = document.querySelector('.screenshot');
const img = new Image()
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
  imgTag.src = this.src;
  setTimeout(reload, 1000)
})
img.addEventListener("error", function() {
  setTimeout(reload, 1000)
})

const reload = () => {
  img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/' +Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 100 + 1) + 100)
};
reload()
```

```html
<img class="screenshot" src="" />
```

Comment: I would like to not lose the previous image in case the next one is a blank (error)